# How do you change camera safe area transparency?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I'm trying to change red-circled area so that it is entirely black.  I don't want to preview what is outside of my camera.  Any idea on how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is called the *passepartout*.  It can be changed or disabled (with the camera selected) under the *Object Data* properties panel > *Display* rollout.

[image]

Note: the [Amaranth Toolset](http://pablovazquez.org/amaranth/) addon adds a passepartout slider to the *Specials* <kbd>W</kbd> menu when in camera view.

Comment: It seems there is no `passepartout` at blender 2.80, where else can I find it?

Comment: In blender 2.80 `passepartout` is in the camera settings (i.e. the camera context panel when you have a camera object selected), under `Viewport Display`

Answer (score 5):

You want to edit the alpha value of something called "passepartout" which can be found in the camera settings. An alpha-value of 1 will make the area outside of your camera view completely black.

The screenshot below shows where you can find the setting.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Blender 2.80 its in the Properties Editor, Camera context ("Object Data"), Viewport Display, `Passepartout`:

[image]