# How do I change the viewable boundary within camera 0

Tags: rendering, camera

I can't seem to figure out how to enlarge the viewable area in Camera 0 in order to see how to position object I want rendered. Cntrl + B gives me  crosshairs to redraw but does not allow to redraw the viewable area larger.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is not about pointing a camera which the provided 'related' link explains, but rather how to ENLARGE that little viewable square into something I can actually see. I'll repost the picture to show a RED boundary of what I mean and how big it *should* be.

Comment: Press **Home** see also:http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44247/how-to-increase-camera-view-area/44264#44264

Comment: To enlarge it you should uncheck `Lock Camera to View` and simply rotate the mouse wheel up or use method which @cegaton provided.

Comment: Pressing Home will make the camera view fit the screen even  when Lock Camera to View is enabled.