# Move the camera view display back to the center of the screen.

Tags: 3d-view, interface, camera

Something strange happened yesterday when I was working on a model. The camera just moved to the right in preview, and I have no idea what I did, nor what to search for. I'm not really sure what to do to get it back to the center..

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: As far as I know, there is no rule about that: you can shift the view even whilst you are in camera view.

Comment: press the home key to center the camera view. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44264/1853

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In camera-view, press <kbd>shift</kbd> + middle mousebutton, then move your mouse and reposition your cameraview.

Alternatively your keyboard might have <kbd>Pos1</kbd>, works for you as well.